# Error when trying to download data output to CSV file using pgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin-4

Just switched to pgAdmin 4 Version 2.1 from pgAdmin 3 and encountered an error when trying to download the data output from my query to a CSV file. The query executed without issue. The issue is when I'm trying to download the data. The error I'm getting is:

```
"ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DROP"
LINE 1: ...LARE "CURSOR:CONN:196190" CURSOR WITHOUT HOLD FOR DROP TABLE...
                                                             ^
"
```

Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.